# Ajax binding ERROR in version 2013.1.319 for numeric columns

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I try to test ajax binding data in grid.
 In case of data column is numeric (int, double, float etc.) we get error or dictionary and model data type incompatibility:
 The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.

This happens in version 1.319. Earlier in version of 1.315 it worked fine.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Ajax()
{
return View();
}

public ActionResult AjaxRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
var persons = new List<Person>()
{
new Person() {Id = 1, Name = "Jack", Age = 13},
new Person() {Id = 2, Name = "Riley", Age = 45},
new Person() {Id = 3, Name = "William", Age = 34},
new Person() {Id = 4, Name = "Oliver", Age = 66},
new Person() {Id = 5, Name = "Lachlan", Age = 35},
new Person() {Id = 6, Name = "Thomas", Age = 53},
new Person() {Id = 7, Name = "Lachlan", Age = 24},
new Person() {Id = 8, Name = "John", Age = 54},
new Person() {Id = 9, Name = "Alex", Age = 19},
new Person() {Id = 10, Name = "Victor", Age = 39},
new Person() {Id = 11, Name = "Joshua", Age = 33}
};
return Json(persons.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
}

public class Person
{
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Controllers.Person>()    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Age);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(8)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
        .Read("AjaxRead", "Grid")
    )
)
```

If I change the code as follows

```
public class Person
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataType("Integer")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

error does not occur.

I do not want to set attributes for all numeric fields of all classes of my application, especially that in the previous version it worked fine.

But if not, please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you,
Vlad